# Unable to have a successful gradle sync with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.1.0'

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, google-play-services

I added a `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.1.0'` in my app dependecies but the messages log in my android studio displays `Failed to resolve : com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.1.0`

Comment: I hope it helps u to solve this question [here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33577258/4554245)

Answer (score 0):

Auth package was created in version 8.3.0, not 8.1.0. To use it you'll need to update all play services to 8.3.0.

Refer to the official doc for help: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: thanks for your response, now its getting clear, do you mean that google auth is new  and can only be added to dependencies if the version is 8.3.0?

Comment: Not sure. But regardless of this, it seems that 8.1.0 is not in my local maven repository. Can you check your sdk path if it you have 8.1.0 folder here:

`SDK_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/`

I only have 8.3.0 so I assumed it was only introduced then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
}
```