# Android studio 3.0.1 : Execution failed for task 'app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, android-studio

Friends, I had recently started working on Android if you notice some basic mistake please forgive.

Here is my problem.

I tried to resolve on issue from last 2 days but not getting any success.
Recently, I had upgrade my Android studio to 3.0.1 and tried to compile my project but I faced following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.0.

Please check my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //adding volley library
    //Picasso
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    //    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyzy.abc.sdf"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
//        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-    android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true // This must be first
            minifyEnabled true   // This must be after shrinkResources
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICEi5'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
productFlavors {
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

here is my project setting
[image: project settings]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572465/gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices

Answer (score 0):

```
Upgrade your firebase and google versions

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'

to
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
```