# NativeScript | Can't run Android app: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

Cannot build & run Android application using the NativeScript command:

```
tns run android
```

I get this error in the console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.0.
```

I tried removing the Android platform from the project and than adding it again but it doesn't work.

How do I update the google-services plugin?
I don't have any dependencies in my app.gradle file.

Here's my app.gradle file:

```
// Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
//dependencies {
//  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//}

android {
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "com.grizlizli.app"
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}
```

Comment: please refer this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834772/4748607)

Comment: just updated my question. @NiravBhavsar

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue by updating nativescript dependencies and removing *nativescript-push-notifications* dependency.