# ionic build failed Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

**I am trying to create ionic build getting an error like:**

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
20 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 19 up-to-date
/home/user/Documents/project/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I tried many solutions but unable to solve yet.

Comment: Have you tried all solutions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572465/gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices

Comment: @AzzamAsghar the solution is there, need to delete apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' that is already commented in my retailordering-FCMPlugin.gradle file

Comment: I had to waste almost one full day with this error its really hard to figure out and is mostly related to version issues especially after an update by google in android. In my case it was an issue with a firebase plugin its version was not compatible with my app. So yeah its all about just trial and error

Comment: @AzzamAsghar, for now, you have any solutions for that??

Comment: There isn't a definite solution one thing works for some and not for other. All you can do is try out different solutions and look at your plugins. Here is another thread https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/274