# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. Failed to delete: \google-services\debug

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am keep getting below error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Failed to delete: D:\Program\ReactNative\MobileSC_New\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug
>   **this is my app level gradle file**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

// Need to set this when we have variant setup
//project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
//        debug: ".env.dev",
//        release: ".env",
//        staging: ".env",
//]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobilesc"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.env.get("APP_VERSION_CODE").toInteger()
        versionName project.env.get("APP_VERSION_NUMBER")

        multiDexEnabled true

//        manifestPlaceholders = [
//                FABRIC_API_KEY:project.env.get("FABRIC_API_KEY"),
//                GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY:project.env.get("GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY")
//        ]
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.mobilesc"

    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"false"]
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"true"]
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }


    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' // <-- Add this line if you wish to use badge on Android
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// CRASH ISSUE: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2411
// WORKAROUND for com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1676#issuecomment-441243419
//googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

**this is my project level gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
//        maven {
//            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
//            name 'Google'
//        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

//    subprojects {
//        afterEvaluate {project ->
//            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
//                android {
//                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
//                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
//                }
//            }
//        }
//    }
}
```

i've try to follow this topic but none of them work
[Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572465/gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just delete build folder inside android/app/ and run as an administrator your cmd.

Comment: tried second time, its seem like your way fix the bugs but another show. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A little late but it might help somebody - make sure you did not forget to add your `google-services.json` to the project folder.