# React Native | 'react-native run-android' command needs to be run twice to compile

Tags: react-native, android-studio

The 'react-native run-android' command throws the error displayed below on first compile even though I've set my android build path correctly
However, it works fine on every alternate compile.

I tried looking for the solution in both android and react-native docs.

```
PS C:\Directory> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1044 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0-alpha09.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :react-native-screens
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0-alpha09.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0-alpha09.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0-alpha09.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Parsing json file: C:Directory\android\app\google-services.json

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1-rc-1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
44 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 42 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Failed to delete: C:\Directory\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Failed to delete: C:\Directory\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Directory\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Directory\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Directory\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Directory\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

Please help if anyone has seen the same error before.

Comment: You can try this link:- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572465/gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices

Comment: It's worked or not?

Comment: Nope ! The problem persists...

Comment: Did you added the google-services.json file in your android folder?. if it's exist check the path of the file.  should go into android/app/ folder.

Comment: It's worked or not?

Comment: Unfortunately not.