# Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'. > Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I've checked this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834772/13519865

It tells us to remove this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Removing the line as asked completes the build, but I can't use Firebase (ofc!), it caused a new error, which tells me to add the line:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085096/13519865

So, I'm stuck in a loop here.
Related code sample added here https://github.com/Cyberavater/A.Reader

Comment: Those are some kind of old answers. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed), it might help.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

**Edit:** October 16rd, 2023

The same issue seems to appear with the latest [Android Studio Electric Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) where you need to specify the Gradle version to be `8.1.3` and Google Services `4.4.0`. I have tried to see if the `5.0.0` version works but I got:

> Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

So here are the working versions:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.3' apply false
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
}
```

---

**Edit:** August 15rd, 2023

The same issue seems to appear with the latest [Android Studio Electric Giraffe](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) where you need to specify the Gradle version to be `8.1.0` and Google Services `4.3.15`. I have **not** tested if it's working with `5.0.0`.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

---

**Edit:** March 24rd, 2023

The same issue seems to appear with the latest [Android Studio Electric Eel](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) where you need to specify the Gradle version to be `7.4.0` and Google Services `4.3.15`.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

---

**Edit:** January 4th, 2023

I have seen the same issue with the latest [Android Studio Dolphin](https://developer.android.com/studio/past-releases/past-android-studio-releases/as-dolphin-release-notes) release, where you need to specify the Gradle version to be `7.3.1` and Google Services `4.3.14`.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
```

---

According to the new [Chipmunk](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) update of Android Studio, if you need to use Google Services, you have to add the following lines of code inside your build.gradle (Project) file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And inside your build.gradle (Module) file, the following plugin IDs:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
}
```

Comment: Hello, it seems the is a problem still holds. When I used version 4.3.0 following here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed it was working, but using version 4.3.10 am having the same issue.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'

Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

Comment: Try to use the latest `7.2.0` for Gradle or downgrade it to `4.3.0`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Changing it to "7.2.0" worked, Thanks! but isn't '7.4.0-alpha01' more latest? (already latest as it was already '7.4.0-alpha01' by default).

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to work with stable versions. It's up to you to decide if you want to use that one, or not.

Comment: This did not help me and in fact sent me down another rabbit hole of build errors. Roberto Leinardi answer should be accepted as it worked like a charm. So it appears to be gradle and GMS compatibility issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo I can up vote it if you remove the 2nd half of the plugins and clean task portion from your answer. I do not believe they are related to the issue. The reason is my code already had plugin definition and the cleanup task even before the AS upgrade. The only thing that made any difference was version upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: @MGDeveloper I don't understand what you mean by "the 2nd half". Please edit my answer, to understand it more clearly. There is an `edit` button right under it.

Comment: If anyone gets this issue in future. This is clearly a version mismatch issue. Try by upgrading version (gms,gradle build) to the most compatible or try by downgrading build.gradle version to the original state and rest to the latest. This worked for me magically. However if you can figure out technically this is a version mismatch issue.

Comment: It's enough if you just set `4.3.15` as `google-services`!

Comment: Still failing in Android Studio Giraffe

Comment: @HardikMehta Are you using Gradle version `8.1.0` and Google Services `4.3.15` and still fails? I doubt it, as I checked that personally.

Comment: Don't know fails for me  Gradle version 8.1.0 and Google Services 4.3.15 if i degrade  Gradle version to 7.4 then works fine

Comment: Thanks for this, I only needed to edit the Google services to 4.3.15

Comment: @AlexMamo where to add `plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
}` in `gradle` file ??

Comment: @Moeez Inside build.gradle (Project) file.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please mention that where I should place both ?

Comment: `buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

Comment: @Moeez It's hard to read your unformatted code in the comment. Please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Agreed, this fixed it for me. I previously used the old Firebase authentication method (using Json). After updating my app to the latest flutter + firebase versions I had to authenticate using Flutterfire instead (which then led to the "missing GOOGLE AD_ID" issues), and THEN I had to follow  this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774667/2439989 to get it to export without any other errors. Now I genuinely don't know what I need to take out and leave in the gradle.build file, so both varients have been left in there. But it works.

Comment: @Delmontee Good to hear that, Delmontee.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed Google Services to go up to 4.4.0, and didn't need gradle version or AGP version (both till 7+) and this worked for me (finally!) on Android Studio Hedgehog

Answer (score 348):

This issue started after updating the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to version `7.3.0` and was fixed for me after updating the `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `4.3.14`.

Comment: Thanks @Robert 
This answer fixed the issue. Upgraded Android Studio to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 and Gradle to 7.4.1. 

'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'  classpath in build.gradle fixed the issue.

Comment: Same for me. Going from `4.3.10` tot `4.3.14` fixed it for me.

Comment: Agreed, this fixed it for me. I previously used the old Firebase authentication method (using Json). After updating my app to the latest flutter + firebase versions I had to authenticate using Flutterfire instead (which then led to some "missing GOOGLE AD_ID" issues), and THEN I had to follow the information above to get it to export without the mentioned error. Now I genuinely don't know what I need to take out and leave in the gradle.build file, so both  varients have been left in there.

Comment: 2024 and this still worked and fixed "E/FA      ( 5048): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https

"

Answer (score 90):

change this line in >> android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Comment: This is the only thing I actually needed, thanks

Answer (score 17):

2023: This worked for me.

from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

Answer (score 15):

Open your android folder then build.gradle and find

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

and finally change `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`
and your code should now look like

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: is there any open bug?

Answer (score 9):

For newbies like myself step by step instructions:

1. Go to 'android/build.gradle'
2. Find dependencies {}
3. Replace there the
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
   with
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
4. Rebuild.

Should work.

---

### The full error text for the search purpose:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.

> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
> > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited

Comment: Excellent! I updated Android Studio to the Flamingo version and a lot of problems arrived. One of them was solved with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issues but after updating the dependency the issues were resolved.

in my project level Gradle file previous it was as below:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**after updating as below, It was working fine with me.**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed with using latest google services plugin from this link:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin?hl=tr

right now link provides like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what version specifically? if version 4.4.0, how is this different than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

In my android/build.gradle for my Flutter project, I had:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

I updated by changing the lines to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

And the errors were resolved. This happened when I moved my Flutter project to a new laptop and the gradle to java versions no longer matched up since I installed the newest version of Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Read this if Alex Mamo's answer does not solve the problem for you.

The new updates of Android Studio prioritize or prefer the settings.gradle file above build.gradle(project) for plugin management. There are two possible solutions.

Solution 1. Update your existing project as follows.

Update your settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
}
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
}
}
rootProject.name = "Your App Name"
include ':app'
```

Update your build.gradle(project). Use your Gradle version, this example uses version 7.3.0, and google-services: 4.3.14.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        google()
        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
    // other plugins in build.gradle(project)
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Add this to your build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // other plugins
}
```

Solution 2. You can create a new project and move all your classes and XML into the new project.

Answer (score 2):

**solved**

Replace classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' with classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' in android/build.gradle

check the latest gs here :
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34900572)

Answer (score 1):

Just update you `com.google.gms:google-services` to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Updating `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services'` to the latest version solved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same error in Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1

By opening  android/build.gradle and upgrading the build gradle version to 7.3.1 and Google services version to 4.3.15 my app worked.

Answer (score 1):

change this line in >> Your project/android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova-Builds: I was missing the following attribute in the config.xml:

`<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />`

In the config.xml you can also set the googleServices version (if you want to apply the answers of the other users in a cordova project without commiting the platforms or plugin directory):
`<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.15" />`

Comment: Yeah nice. Helped me out, but where is the source for that?
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
In **android\build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    ...
}
```

In **android\app\build.gradle**

```
/* on top of file */
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with deleting .idea and .gradle folders from root of your app , an then from main app module ... If this doesn't work , then you must clone your project, making new one with same package name ... This is bug in Android Studio Dolphin , and I solved it with cloning with new project with same package name

Answer (score 0):

First check your build.gradle(project) and paste these code below the plugins and also sync your project.

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter -> `Android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem concerned the app/build.gradle where I tend to set three values: (1) compileSdkVersion, (2) minSdkVersion and (3) targetSdkVersion.

On this occasion I found myself setting four values, because a newer version of Android Studio has given me the option, but I was confused, mixing up the "fourth" value with one of the usual three, but it turns out that the fourth value is one that shouldn't be touched, and if you amend it then you'll go around in circles searching for a way to fix the never-ending error messages - hence my encounter with this post.

**Example**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

If you see the above within your app/build.gradle file, do not amend it, and if you have amended it, copy what you see here or revert to the default values.  Once you set this bit right the error goes away and Flutter runs (if you have set the right settings for the usual three settings).

If this answer helps you, remember to tick it so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android/buil.gradle

replace your dependencies-related code with the following code:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete this lines from your build.gradle file and all related files with google play services ( ads , firebase etc ...)

```
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
     //this  delete   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
     //this  delete   classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Then in your app level  build.gradle file delete this lines

You must delete all files related to google play service ...

```
 plugins {
   
//this  delete ======   id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//this  delete =========   id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    // Other plugins here if pre-existing if they related to google play services 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Flutter project I solved this by:

1. going to `android/build.gradle`

`dependencies {`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'`

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

`}`

2. on terminal `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a version incompatibility issue. Try to find the compatible google-services Gradle plugin version for your AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) or downgrade your AGP.

The selected answer is updated (almost regularly) with a compatible pair.

Sadly they don't provide a compatibility matrix and I was only able to find this: https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/google-services-plugin#android-gradle-plugin-compatibility