# Android Studio Dolphin build.gradle file plugin{id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' false id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' false

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle

**im trying to add Firebase to my android project and it needs this steps:**
To make the google-services.json config values accessible to Firebase SDKs, you need the Google services Gradle plugin. android studio dolphin 2021.3.1

Add the plugin as a buildscript dependency to your project-level build.gradle file:

Root-level (project-level) Gradle file (/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
}
```

**but in my build.gradle file, there is nothing like this. it almost empty just this 2 lines:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false

}
```

**i tried to go back to older version but it cause error.
i looked for proxy settings but i couldnt find anything.
i tried to disable firewall and restart nothing happened
I downloaded android chipmunk to another PC but it was game error with 7.2.2**

**build. graddle (app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.proje_15ig'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proje_15ig"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "proje_15ig"
include ':app'
```

**gradle wrapper properties**

```
#Sun Oct 30 18:28:07 TRT 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**gradle properties**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
```

i tried to go back to older version but it cause error.
i looked for proxy settings but i couldnt find anything.
i tried to disable firewall and restart nothing happened

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) answer? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224454/execution-failed-for-task-appmapdebugsourcesetpaths-error-while-evaluatin/72226009#72226009)?

Comment: I solved my problem by auto-connecting firebase in android studio. (Tools -> Firebase) They really need to update the web documentation. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Add at the top of the project level Gradle file

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        }
}
```

[You can follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkxV5.png)