# how to add com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14 in my android project?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

When I read this doc: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin they say :

> As part of enabling Google APIs or Firebase services in your Android application you may have to add the google-services plugin to
> your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
>     // ...
> }
> ```

then they say also :

> Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you
> have enabled. This step requires that you apply the Google Services
> Gradle plugin in your app/build.gradle file, like so: apply plugin:
> 'com.google.gms.google-services'

so i start a blank new android project in the very last version of android studio and I have for the root build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

and in app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'app.dependencieswalker'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.dependencieswalker"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation "com.alcinoe:alcinoe-firebase:1.0.0"
}
```

so where I must add the

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    // ...
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ?
```

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224454/execution-failed-for-task-appmapdebugsourcesetpaths-error-while-evaluatin/72226009#72226009)? Does it help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your **root** `build.gradle` file in the `plugins` block add

```
plugins {
    //....
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
}
```

Then apply it in the module `build.gradle` file with:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: For flutter, I also needed to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'` in build.gradle `dependencies` block.