# ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. error in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement fire base in app but i'm getting this error
** Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.**
I searched on various site for the solution and on every site they are telling to change the dependencies version to recommended i did that too but not worked for me.

here is all the dependencies in build.gradle (project)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.chatzz'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chatzz"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.0'


}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false

}
```

i have changed to recommended version.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224454/execution-failed-for-task-appmapdebugsourcesetpaths-error-while-evaluatin/72226009#72226009) will help.