# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.grable':17

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I had an error when I linked my Android studio program with Firebase. I don't understand how to fix this error, please help me upgrade it.

build.gradle(My Web) - Source Code

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {// Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {// Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyEux.png)

Help me solve this error

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224454/execution-failed-for-task-appmapdebugsourcesetpaths-error-while-evaluatin/72226009#72226009) help?