# main.dart when i run the project any solution?

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:generateDebugSources'.

> Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'GoogleServicesTask'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please check this link. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834772/16616583

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.